# ReactJS: how can I know what parameters are passed automatically from a component when onChange is triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, dropdown, semantic-ui

This is probably a very newbie question, but I can't figure out how to know what parameters are passed to a function. Let me show you what I mean:

I have the following code in my constructor:

```
this.handleFormInput = this.handleFormInput.bind(this);
```

And then:

```
  handleFormInput(event) {
    console.log('event' + event.target.name);
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

And finally the form:

```
    <Form>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Field style={{width: '90%'}}>
          <input placeholder='Section title'
            id={section.id}
            name='title'
            value={section.title}
            onChange={this.handleInput}
          />
        </Form.Field>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
```

So far so good: the event parameter is passed automatically and I can reach it by adding it as a parameter in my function.

Now I have a Dropdown component. In the constructor I have:

```
this.handleDropDownInput = this.handleDropDownInput.bind(this);
```

The function:

```
  handleDropDownInput(event, data) {
    console.log('value ' + data.value);
    this.setState({
      [data.name]: data.value
    })
  }
```

Then the `semantic-ui` Dropdown:

```
      <Dropdown
        fluid
        placeholder='Language'
        search
        selection
        options={languages}
        defaultValue='gb'
        name='language'
        onChange={this.handleDropDownInput}
      />
```

**Why I have to use the 'data' parameter to get the value on the Dropdown component?** Why I can't use just the event? How can I know what parameters are passed automatically when onChange is triggered?

Is it appropriate to have a different function for different input components (dropdown, form fields etc)? Can and should I make one function to manage all user input?

For example, I came up with this function to handle both dropdown and form fields onChange events:

```
  handleInput(event, data) {
    if (data !== undefined) {
      console.log('value ' + data.value);
      this.setState({
        [data.name]: data.value
      })
    } else {
      console.log('event ' + event.target.name);
      this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value

      })
    }
```

Is it good or bad practice? Thanks.

Comment: a dropdown `event` is different from a change event on an input. Probably semantic-ui defined a data key to pass through. thats the limitation of the library you are using.

Comment: I would recommend you keep your handler functions different rather than trying to merge them. Since the data types are different you should keep a 1:1 correlation there

Comment: Thank you. So can I find out what parameters are automatically passed programmatically?

Comment: you can [read the docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/) on how they pass parameters. You could define an additional param you send where you identify these if you want. But id recommend to keep your handler functions separate and not merge them.

Comment: Thank you. I was browsing the docs but I could not find this information. And yes, I will keep the function separated.

Comment: PS if I can't find this information on the docs, is it appropriate to open a pull request asking for it? I have never done a PR before but I would like to be more active to the github community. I think that could be a starting point.

Comment: The documentation I linked to is not sufficient?

Comment: I'm browsing it right now but I can't find any information about the issue. If after thoughtfully searching I can't find it, would it be ok to ask?

Comment: It's there. Under the button called `props`

Comment: I found it. Thanks. Sorry, it's a bit challenging for someone new to find out the correct information.

Comment: No worries! That's why we're here to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript there are a few ways you can get all the arguments, depending on your environment.

In pre-es6 javascript (pre "strict mode," which is what es6 modules default to) there was a dynamic variable called "arguments." You can see a reference to it here: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

In newer es6 style environments, you can use what is called "rest parameter syntax" to get something similar, which will be an array of the arguments. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

In general, that information should be in the docs for the library or react component you are using.

```js
function someFn(...args) {
  console.log(args)
}

someFn("hey", "there");
```